# Blog posts grid view

Tags: gridview, prestashop

I am using a blog module in my prestashop, heree is the file that lists the posts, could you please help me to make it a grid view 2 or 3 posts per line

```
{if isset($nbposts)}
<!-- Post list -->
<div id="post_list" class="post-list">
{foreach from=$nbposts item=post name=nbposts}
    <section class="a-post">
        <div class="date">
            <span class="month">{$post.date_add|date_format:"%b"}</span>
            <span class="day">{$post.date_add|date_format:"%d"}</span>
            <span class="year">{$post.date_add|date_format:"%Y"}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="name">
            <a href="{$post.link|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" title="">{$post.name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}</a>
            <div class="meta">
                <span class="author">{$post.author|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}</span>
                <span class="in-cols">{$post.in_collections|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}</span>
                {if $post.num_comment > 0}<span class="num-comment">{$post.num_comment} {l s='Comment(s)' mod='nextblog'}</span>{/if}
            </div>
        </div>
        {if $post.image}
            <div class="image">
            <a href="{$post.link|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" title="{$post.name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}">
                <img src="{$post.image}" alt="{$post.name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" />
            </a>
            </div>
        {/if}
        <div class="description nsb">
            {$post.description_short|escape:'UTF-8'}
        </div>
        <div class="view">
            <a class="button post-button" href="{$post.link|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" title="{l s='Read More' mod='nextblog'}">{l s='Read More' mod='nextblog'}</a>
        </div>
    </section>
{/foreach}
</div>
<!-- /Post list -->
```

{/if}

Comment: yes I am not a developer but I can understand examples and adapt them, so you can guide me not do it for me, Thanks in advance

Comment: What is Your current theme? default-bootstrap?

Comment: no it is not it's called The Manier, but the above code is the code called to display posts

Answer (score 0):

If You are using default-boostrap theme use this code.

If You want to have 2 posts in a row use "col-md-6" in section class (like in example), if 3 just use "col-md-4" instead.

```
 {if isset($nbposts)}
 <!-- Post list -->
 <div id="post_list" class="post-list col-md-12">
 {foreach from=$nbposts item=post name=nbposts}
<section class="a-post col-md-6">
    <div class="date">
        <span class="month">{$post.date_add|date_format:"%b"}</span>
        <span class="day">{$post.date_add|date_format:"%d"}</span>
        <span class="year">{$post.date_add|date_format:"%Y"}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="name">
        <a href="{$post.link|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" title="">{$post.name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}</a>
        <div class="meta">
            <span class="author">{$post.author|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}</span>
            <span class="in-cols">{$post.in_collections|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}</span>
            {if $post.num_comment > 0}<span class="num-comment">{$post.num_comment} {l s='Comment(s)' mod='nextblog'}</span>{/if}
        </div>
    </div>
    {if $post.image}
        <div class="image">
        <a href="{$post.link|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" title="{$post.name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}">
            <img src="{$post.image}" alt="{$post.name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" />
        </a>
        </div>
    {/if}
    <div class="description nsb">
        {$post.description_short|escape:'UTF-8'}
    </div>
    <div class="view">
        <a class="button post-button" href="{$post.link|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" title="{l s='Read More' mod='nextblog'}">{l s='Read More' mod='nextblog'}</a>
    </div>
</section>
 {/foreach}
 </div>
 <!-- /Post list -->

 {/if}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, the columns work, but there is only one column always, the 2, 3 or 4 posts per row settings only affects the columns width.